# How to edit user controller in devise so I can update my user's profile without devise

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I have an app that uses devise for sign up and login. I'm trying to create the edit account page.

I was wondering if I can update the user information without using devise elements whatsoever, and I want to edit the controller for User.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure I understand your question, but I think you want to create a `UsersController#edit` action? There are plenty of resources on the internet about how to create a controller in rails; I'm voting to close this as too broad, unless you have a clearer, more specific question (with a code sample) in mind.

Comment: run this on your console and then you will get your devise controller `rails generate devise:controllers users`

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use actions provided by devise, you can generate your own standard controller and implement edit action.

`rails g controller Users edit`

If you want to customize devise edit profile controller, then look at https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#configuring-controllers this link, it tells how to customize views and controllers.